# Basic Functors in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functor

I know that Functor typeclass is defined like so:

```
class Functor f where  
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

In my course it says that this is how a list is made an instance of functor:

```
instance Functor [] where  
    fmap = map
```

Is `[] a` some kind of synonym for `[a]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is `[] a` some kind of synonym for `[a]`

Yes, precisely. There's no difference between the two types: the latter is only a pretty notation for the former.

In Haskell, all types follow the syntax `T arg1 arg2 ...` where `T` is some type constructor, but some of them also have pretty notations hard-coded in the language for human convenience. Here's a few:

```
a -> b   means (->) a b
[a]      means [] a
(a,b)    means (,) a b
(a,b,c)  means (,,) a b c
... ditto for other tuple types
```

Because of this, one can find a functor instance such as `instance Functor ((->) a)` whose `fmap` has type

```
(x -> y) -> ((->) a x) -> ((->) a y)
```

which can also be written

```
(x -> y) -> (a -> x) -> (a -> y)
```

Such `fmap` is just function composition, i.e., `fmap = (.)`.